# How does one do user authentication in Safari if it defaults to block cookies? (devise, angular-devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, devise

I realize this is probably a stupid question but I have put in about 16 hours of googling and haven't even come close to figuring this out.

I have AngularJS running on top of Rails (4.2), consuming JSON.  Authentication is currently done with Devise and angular-devise.  There are no problems with authentication when in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari with cookies allowed.  The problem is Safari defaults to reject cookies and apparently 80% of my would-be-users are using Safari and rejecting all cookies.  A User can log into the app but the session is immediately lost and any further requests requiring authentication fail.

I initially thought it was an issue with the Heroku iframe but according to the 'support' message below it's not and I'm SOL.

> This log entry Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms tells me that the
>   session information that the browser is sending to your server is
>   invalid or expired. Your API then rejects the request.
>
> This makes sense if Safari is set to reject any cookies from the
>   website. Session information will not be stored and the API server
>   will reject any requests.
>
> I'm afraid this isn't a Heroku issue and so there's not much we can do
>   from our side on this. However, if I'm wrong on that, please let us
>   know and we can investigate further.

I played around with Safari and tried signing into a bunch of my accounts with cookies blocked and nothing worked, facebook was even kind enough to tell me to turn on cookies.  Follow up question: how in the world are all these people just now having trouble with a website because of blocked cookies?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that Safari does not block all cookies by default, but only blocks **3rd party** cookies by default.

It's possible you're encountering this problem during development due to a mismatch between your development server's domain and the domain of the dropped cookie for Devise and angular-devise.  If you inspect those cookies, you might find some additional information.  Good luck.

"By default, Safari accepts cookies and website data only from websites you visit. This helps prevent certain advertisers from storing data on your Mac. You can change options in Safari preferences so that Safari always accepts or always blocks cookies and other website data."